# A* nosolution issue

Tags: java

I have a question according to A*-Algorithm, which I have implemented in Java.
So, I have a grid of nodes with randomly generated obstacles and a Player, who can walk over the grid.
But I got a Problem. If I click on an obstacle no path is generated, but this is exactly what I want to. So I want to generate the best path the Point I click on to especially to an obstacle.
My idea is to take a boolean flag, but I never get my Problem solved. Maybe some of u guys see the Problem.

Heres the A*-Method:

```
public List<Node> findPath(int startx,int starty,int endx,int endy){

    for(int i = 0;i<cols;i++){
        for(int j = 0;j<rows;j++){
            grid[i][j] = new Node(i,j,obstacles[i][j]);
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0;i<cols;i++){
        for(int j = 0;j<rows;j++){
            grid[i][j].addNeighbours(grid);
        }
    }

    List<Node> openList = new ArrayList<Node>();
    List<Node> closedList = new ArrayList<Node>();

    Node start = grid[startx][starty];
    Node end = grid[endx][endy];

    openList.add(start);


        while(openList.size() > 0){

            int winner = 0;
            for(int i = 0;i <openList.size();i++){
                if(openList.get(i).f < openList.get(winner).f){
                    winner = i;
                }
            }

            Node current = openList.get(winner);
            openList.remove(current);
            closedList.add(current);

            if(nosolution==false){
                if(current == end){
                    List<Node> path = new ArrayList<Node>();
                    Node tmp = current;
                    path.add(tmp);
                    while(tmp.previous!=null){
                        path.add(tmp);
                        tmp = tmp.previous;
                    }
                    openList.clear();
                    closedList.clear();
                    Collections.reverse(path);
                    return path;
                }
            }else{
                               nosolution=true;
                            }


            List<Node> neighbours = current.neighbours;

            for(int i = 0;i<neighbours.size();i++){

                Node neighbour = neighbours.get(i);

                if(!closedList.contains(neighbour) && !neighbour.obstacle){
                    int tempG = current.g + 1;
                    boolean newPath = false;
                    if(openList.contains(neighbour)){
                        if(tempG < neighbour.g){
                            neighbour.g = tempG;
                            newPath = true;
                        }
                    }
                    else{
                        neighbour.g = tempG;
                        newPath = true;
                        openList.add(neighbour);
                    }
                    if(newPath){
                        neighbour.h = heuristic(neighbour,end);
                        neighbour.f = neighbour.g + neighbour.h;
                        neighbour.previous = current;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: It is unlcear what your problem is. Please try to break down the problem, give a concrete example and, if possible, simplify your code base (e.g. try to  isolate the part of your code that causes the problem).

Comment: ok i understood.

Comment: i hope u understood what i graphically want to do. I want to know, how i can generate a new path and this path should be visible on the map even if i click on an obstacle on the map.So, at the Moment this method Returns null if theres no path found and no path is generated. But want this method not to return null, i want to generate the best path to the Point i clicked on so i can see the path. I tried out the wildest Things with boolean flags but it doesnt work. Thats the Point ineed some help.

Comment: Well, basically, your A* algorithm doesn't works ? what tells you that it returns null when there is no path because it didn't found a path (rather than because it couldn't have found any even if there was one.) ? From a quick look at your code, I'm not even sure you're looping mroe than one time. if your "noSolution" is false originally, how can it ever be true ? if it's  true originally ? how could you ever switch it to get the path ? Anyway, try to use debugging or put some logs.

Comment: Well my a* works great. I

Comment: Sorry i cant understand what u want me to say with ur answer. Ist very friendly of u that ur interessted in my question but i guess u missunderstood my question.

Comment: The Point is my find path method Returns null if theres no path found. But i want to find a path even if i click on an obstacle.

Comment: And i always Loop through the findPath method. And the nosolution flag is my try to handle my issue. In my update method i say that if path not null than generate one and if i click on an obstacle the console tells me that the path is null.

Comment: I have a Thread with the runmethod started in the mainmethod. In the run method i got my gameloop with a while Loop. within this Loop i run an update and a render method with 60fps. So the findpath method is called in the update method of the Player. Maybe now u understand???

Comment: You need to clarify two things. 1) When you select an obstacle as a target, what do you want? I suppose it is the shortest path to the walkable Node closest to the obstacle (straight line). 2) When pathfinder has no solution, it may be that the way is blocked far before approaching the obstacle. Do you still want the shortest path to the walkable Node closest to the obstacle which may be quite far, or is there a criiteria (for example within a max distance) where you want to give up ?

Comment: As I said i want it like in ur 1 proposal.

Answer (score 0):

When no solution is found, and you still want to know the best solution that got closest to your destination, then look at the `closedList` and pick the `Node` with the smallest distance to the destination.

For a better answer, provide the code to `Node` as well if you need more help.

**Update**

Node has the `x` and `y`.  Look through all the closed nodes, find the one closest to the target.  Then construct a path using the `previous` field.

Since there might be many closed nodes, you may want to adjust the algorithm a bit to keep track of the closest node instead, and return that path when no solution exists.

Answer (score 0):

Here the Node class:

```
public class Node{

public int x;
public int y;
public int g;
public int h;
public int f;
public List<Node> neighbours;
public Node previous;
public boolean obstacle;

public Node(int x,int y,boolean obstacle) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.g = 0;
    this.h = 0;
    this.f = 0;
    this.previous = null;
    this.obstacle = obstacle;
    this.neighbours = new ArrayList<Node>(); 
}

public List<Node> addNeighbours(Node[][] grid){

    int x = this.x;
    int y = this.y;

    if(x < 25 - 1){
        neighbours.add(grid[x+1][y]);
    }
    if(x > 0){
        neighbours.add(grid[x-1][y]);
    }       
    if(y < 20 - 1){
        neighbours.add(grid[x][y+1]);
    }
    if(y > 0){
        neighbours.add(grid[x][y-1]);
    }

    return neighbours;

}
```

Comment: I just have to figure out some Things, but i understood what u said. Thx.

Comment: I have a question:

Comment: Is it possible to recalculate the end Node and give him the Position of the last walkable Node and then recalculate the path?

Comment: Hi again, i understood ur proposals, but i cant figure it out. i Need some more concrete help in the Code. All i tried didnt work and im quite diappointed that it dont work. I will post the Code of what i got so far in the A* method.

Answer (score 0):

public ArrayList findPath(int startx,int starty,int endx,int endy){

```
    List<Node> openList = new ArrayList<Node>();
    List<Node> closedList = new ArrayList<Node>();

    Node start = grid[startx][starty];
    Node end = grid[endx][endy];
    Node closest = start;

    openList.add(start);

    while(!openList.isEmpty()){ 

        int winner = 0;
        for(int i = 0;i <openList.size();i++){
            if(openList.get(i).f < openList.get(winner).f){
                winner = i;
            }
        }

        Node current = openList.get(winner);
        openList.remove(current);
        closedList.add(current);

        if(current == end){
            path = new ArrayList<Node>();
            Node tmp = current;
            path.add(tmp);
            while(tmp.previous!=null){
                path.add(tmp);
                tmp = tmp.previous;
            }
            return path;
        }



        List<Node> neighbours = current.neighbours;

        for(int i = 0;i<neighbours.size();i++){
            Node neighbour = neighbours.get(i);
            int cost = current.g + heuristic(current,neighbour);
            if(openList.contains(neighbour) && cost < neighbour.g){
                openList.remove(neighbour);
            }
            if(closedList.contains(neighbour) && cost < neighbour.g){
                closedList.remove(neighbour);
            }
            if(openList.contains(neighbour) == false && closedList.contains(neighbour) == false && neighbour.obstacle == false){
                neighbour.g = cost;
                int newcost = heuristic(closest,end);
                closest.h = newcost;
                if(neighbour.h < closest.h){
                    closest = neighbour;
                }
                openList.add(neighbour);
                neighbour.f = neighbour.g + neighbour.h;
                neighbour.previous = current;
            }
        }
    }
    if(closest!=end){
        path = new ArrayList<Node>();
        Node tmp = closest;
        path.add(tmp);
        while(tmp.previous!=null){
            path.add(tmp);
            tmp = tmp.previous;
        }
    }

    return path;

}
```